# Using standard validation for read only edit boxes?

Tags: xpages

Some of my recent posts have to do with the fact that I am doing all of my validation in my Submit button.

The reason I am doing this is that I have a button that sets some read only edit boxes.  Well you can configure a validation for a read only edit box but it does not execute at run time.

Since I could not figure this out and wanted to have a consistent look for validation I used my own validation on my Submit button.

Is there a way to validate read only fields?

One nice thing about putting all of the code in the Submit button is that all of the validation code is all in the same place but I can see where it also can cause portability issues when using custom controls.

Also another question is how to fire off validation if my Submit button is not marked as a Submit button.

Comment: Bruce: you should reconsider your approach. When you change your field set (e.g. add or remove) you need to work in 2 locations: your field and your button. Also it is hard to document. The better approach is to use validators - You can render a nice report for them! And you follow a basic principle: one function does one thing. The validator also doesn't care how your form was submitted.

Comment: For the 'set focus' see: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8T5JSS

Answer (score 2):

As Dec says, the ReadOnly flag causes the content of the field to be rendered without the `<input>` tag. This makes validation impossible on the client side and since there is no data being submitted back to the JVM, validation coded on the field is ignored on the submit.

However, the data source `QuerySaveDocument` is triggered. Put your validation in there and/or put it in the fields that are rendered (`readOnly=false`) and be sure to set `disableClientSideValidation="true"` on all fields with validators on them.

Your `QuerySaveDocument` code looks something like this (assuming location is the field which is readOnly).

```
if (personDoc.getItemValueString("Location") == "") {
    @ErrorMessage("The inherited location is blank and that is bad.");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

With this, the field based validators will fire first and if they are all successful the `QuerySaveDocument` fires. This means if any field based validators fail, their messages will appear in your message area but the `QuerySaveDocument` message will not appear. `QuerySaveDocument` messages ONLY appear after all field based validators succeed.

Comment: Yep now I remember that I noticed the input box is not rendered.    Thanks for the solution but it goes back to my inconstant look problem.   If I use the required  validator for regular edit boxes then I get a popup.  If I use @ErrorMessage then I get the error message right on the form.

Comment: If you set the disableClientSideValidation="true" on the fields then you get no more pop ups and all messages are the same. The timing might still be an issue, in which case, do it all in the QuerySaveDocument.

Comment: Great!   Thanks for the tip on disable client side validation.   The only remaining issue I see with server side validation and @ErrorMessage is I can't take the user to the problem field.  Also if I do everything in  QuerySaveDocument then I lose that portability that I mentioned.   What would be nice is if you could put a validator type control on an xPage and don't tie it to any particular field.  Then you could still have client side validation for just about anything.

Comment: You actually can use a database property to switch them off for all XPages in one go.

Comment: You can take the user to the problem field: add an onLoad function that queries fields with the aria-invalid attribute set. Set the focus to the first field.

Answer (score 1):

When a read only field is rendered to the web browser it does not render using `<input>` tags but rather a simple `<span>` tag.

Validation can only be performed on proper input tags so the scenario you are experiencing is correct. There is no field for it to validate in read-only mode.

There is an option to 'display disabled in read only' which will render an `<input disabled="true">` type tag for the field but I'm not sure off the top of my head is validation will work for those fields either because if a field is read-only then there really should be no need for any validation because your programmatically putting the value into the field and you should be validating it programmatically before you add the value.